# HTML5 Server Side Events (SSE)

Tags: java, html, servlets, server-sent-events

I am working on implementing SSE in a Web Application on Java Stack using Servlets.  I have facing 2 key issues currently.  Let me first place my code both for the Web page and the Servlet followed by the issue I am facing.

Web Page Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function registerSSE() {
var source = new EventSource("http://www.sample.com/BootStrap/NotificationServlet");
source.addEventListener('StartProductionRun', function(e) {
    // Get the data and identify the instrument Name/Id
    var dataReceived = e.data;
    document.getElementById(dataReceived + "_button").disabled = true;
    }, false);
}

function StartProduction(instrument) {
var dataString = 'instrumentName='+ instrument; 

// call ajax to submit the form and start the production  run
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/BootStrap/ProductionRunServlet',
    data: dataString,
    success: function() {
        $('#Status').html("<div id='message'></div>"); 
        $('#message').html("<h4 aling=\"centre\">Prudction Run for Instrument " + instrument  + " initiated.</h4>")
        .hide()
        .fadeIn(5000);
    }
});
}

</script>
```

Servlet Code :

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/event-stream;charset=UTF-8");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    NotificationService notificationService = null;

    while (true) {
        notificationService = NotificationService.getInstance();

        if (notificationService.getNotificationCount() > 0 ) {

            String notificationValue = notificationService.getNotification(0);
            String[] keyValue = notificationValue.split(":");

            out.print("event:" + keyValue[0] + "\n");
            out.print("data: " + keyValue[1] + "\n");
            out.print("retry:" + 1000 + "\n\n");

            out.flush();
        }
        else {
            out.print(": time stream \n");
            out.print("retry:" + 1000 + "\n\n");
            out.flush();
        }

       try {
             Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

Now the issues:

1. The Web Page will be viewed by multiple users at the same time.  And I want that the data to be pushed to all the users who viewing that page.   Currently when I am running locally in my machine, even if I open Chrome and Firefox,  I don't get the notification in both the Browsers.  It comes only in one.
2. Also,  If I leave the browser running for some time,  I find that even if the servlet is pushing out data based on certain events.  I don't get the notification on the Browser.

I need to make sure that:
   The notification gets pushed to all the clients who are viewing that particular page irrespective of what they are doing on the page or the page is just used for viewing the information.

Looking forward to all the help I can get to make this working.  Also,  would be interested to know if there are other alternative which I can use.

Answer (score 1):

Your servlet code is working perfectly, although i haven't worked so much on it(once did a jsp project). What i think is, you have missed something in javascript?
I think there should be a timer/thread/loop in javascript too, to get all pushed data continuously. i.e,

```
setInterval(
function(){
// code which needs to run every 5sec
},5000);
```

I hope this will help out a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if `EventSource` is available in that browser before using it. Maybe one of the browsers has not support for it.